# Contending duplicate hubs for "Les maîtres du temps" aka "The Masters of Time"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A relatively popular story ID subject (with six confirmed answers and several additional probable answers) has something of a mess with respect to duplicate management.

The first time that this was asked about was in Feb 2013, and it was answered and accepted then:

1. [80's Animated movie: An old man joins mission to save a boy stranded on a hostile world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil)

Some duplicates were later closed against it:

- [trying to identify SF anime film shown on British TV in 1980s or '90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142585/trying-to-identify-sf-anime-film-shown-on-british-tv-in-1980s-or-90s)
- [Please help to identify an animated movie: a boy lost on a jungle planet (80-90-s)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163072/please-help-to-identify-an-animated-movie-a-boy-lost-on-a-jungle-planet-80-90)

Some years later in May 2018, this movie was asked about and got an accepted answer for a fourth time:

2. [Animation movie (80's-90's) with brain-sucking insects](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188278/animation-movie-80s-90s-with-brain-sucking-insects)

At that time, #1 was closed as a duplicate of #2, despite the fact that #1 was already a duplicate hub. This created a duplicate chain.

Some later duplicates have also been closed against #2:

- [Space-themed cartoon film seen on TV in the mid-80's with a pair of blobby telepathic aliens and relativistic aging](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246918/space-themed-cartoon-film-seen-on-tv-in-the-mid-80s-with-a-pair-of-blobby-telep)
- [Animation (possibly anime) with space station made of two hemispheres](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250725/animation-possibly-anime-with-space-station-made-of-two-hemispheres)

In addition to a new question today that will be a duplicate if its answer is accepted ([1980s sci-fi anime film with a scene where a human boy and an alien are walking through a swamp, and the alien is caught and killed by living vines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261205/1980s-sci-fi-anime-film-with-a-scene-where-a-human-boy-and-an-alien-are-walking)), there is also an old question with an accepted answer that should be closed:

- [Fantasy Animation from the 80's. Companion pulled into ceiling by tentacles. Other turns around and companion is just 'gone'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163070/fantasy-animation-from-the-80s-companion-pulled-into-ceiling-by-tentacles-oth)

What's the best way to resolve this tangle and establish a proper hub question for current and future duplicates?

Answer (score 8):

I pointed all the confirmed duplicates (new and old) to question 2:
[Animation movie (80's-90's) with brain-sucking insects](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188278/animation-movie-80s-90s-with-brain-sucking-insects)

(I think this was the first time I had changed dupe targets without actually reopening any questions.)

Comment: When an ID question has a comment "This is probably one of the best story IDs I've seen" from one of the site's top reviewers, that's a pretty safe choice of dupe target. Good job with your (newish?) dupehammer powers.

Comment: +1 As the asker of the original Duplicate Hub, I agree that Question 2 above is the best choice as Duplicate Hub :)